# Changing location after CommitAnimations

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm using the following code to move a `UIImageView`:

```
shootImg.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Projectile Left 1.png"];
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
shootImg.center = CGPointMake(shootImg.center.x+1000, shootImg.center.y);
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

This works but what I want to do is after `[UIView CommitAnimations];` I want to set the location of `shootImg` using `CGPointMake`. If I just put it after `commitAnimations` then the animation doesn't fully complete. Any suggestions? I'm not using any frameworks like cocos2d and if you need to see any more code just ask.

Answer (score 1):

You could add inside the `[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];` and `[UIView commitAnimations];` add the following line: `[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];` and create this methods on your class: `setAnimationWillStartSelector:` and `setAnimationDidStopSelector:`

so your code will be like this:

```
shootImg.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Projectile Left 1.png"];
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
shootImg.center = CGPointMake(shootImg.center.x+1000, shootImg.center.y);
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

and on your class this methods:

```
+ (void)setAnimationDidStopSelector:(SEL)selector
+ (void)setAnimationWillStartSelector:(SEL)selector
```

if you like to see more i recommend the documentation for UIView [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/setAnimationDelegate%3a)